# How to bring properties of Uibinder Widgets into CSS in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt, gwtp

Ok, in .xml file, this works ok.

```
<g:FlexTable ui:field="wishlistFlexTable"  borderWidth="1" cellPadding="5" />
```

Note: we got similar set methods for FlexTable when coding in Gwt: setBorderWidth & setCellPadding.

However, if we bring borderWidth & cellPadding into css, it won't work
in Css,

```
.gwtFlexTable{
   borderWidth:1;
   cellPadding:5;
}
```

in xml

```
<g:FlexTable ui:field="wishlistFlexTable"  addStyleNames="{res.css.gwtFlexTable}"  />
```

So how to bring properties of Uibinder Widgets into CSS in GWT?

Answer (score 2):

I hink your CSS is just wrong:

```
.gwtFlexTable{
   border-width:1px;
   cell-padding:5px;
}
```

You forgot the units (They are obligatory in CSS).
and `borderWidth` must be written as `border-width`

Comment: i put background:orange; into .gwtFlexTable{} & it worked fine. So using border-width & cell-padding is not right way.

Comment: Are you sure that `cell-padding`, etc are even valid CSS properties that do what you are asking for? At least `border-width` is a real thing, but that doesn't have the same effect as calling the setter (i.e. setting the property in uibinder).

Answer (score 0):

anyway, i found this code, it's work ok

```
.flexTable td{
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    padding: 3px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any css classes you put in your `<ui:style>` get obfuscated at runtime, making them into alphanumeric strings. So your `.gwtFlexTable` would look something like `.A87GFESAF`. To allow external CSS class names to style your table, you'd have to declare your styleNames without the braces `{}` as such:

```
<g:FlexTable ui:field="wishlistFlexTable"  addStyleNames="gwtFlexTable"  />
```

or if you want to style with both external classes AND internal `<ui:style>`s, you can mix CSS classes:

```
<g:FlexTable ui:field="wishlistFlexTable"  addStyleNames="{res.css.gwtFlexTable} gwtFlexTable"  />
<!-- where {res.css.gwtFlexTable} is a ui:style name and gwtFlexTable is an unobfuscated CSS selector -->
```